# bash: completely replace a folder with cp

Tags: bash, cp

I have a question concerning the "cp"-command:
I have to copy folders to a directory. For me two different scenarios exist. In the first scenario folders with the same name don't exist. That's simple so far:

```
ls test/folder1/
file1  file2
ls test/destination/

cp -r -v test/folder1/ test/destination/
»test/folder1/“ -> »test/destination/folder1“
»test/folder1/file1“ -> »test/destination/folder1/file1“
»test/folder1/file2“ -> »test/destination/folder1/file2“
```

In the second scenario a folder with the same name exists. These files have different names than the ones in the source folder. What I actually want is that the folder in the destination directory will be completely replaced by the source folder (if files with the same name exist they should be overriden; if files don't exist in the source directory they should be deleted).

```
ls test/folder1/
file1  file2
ls test/destination/
folder1
ls test/destination/folder1/
file3  file4

cp -r -v test/folder1/ test/destination/
»test/folder1/file1“ -> »test/destination/folder1/file1“
»test/folder1/file2“ -> »test/destination/folder1/file2“


ls test/destination/folder1/
file1  file2  file3  file4
```

It would probably be possible with something like

```
if [ -d destination/$foldername ]
then
rm -r /destination/$foldername
cp-r -v test/$foldername/ test/destination/$foldername
else
cp-r -v test/$foldername/ test/destination/$foldername
fi
```

but I was wondering if there is a better solution to that.

Thanks already!

Comment: i think that is the best. no better solution.

Comment: There's no need to test for the destination existing first if you don't care about it. Just use `rm -rf "test/destination/$foldername"` and then `cp`.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr, a 7-line solution is by no means better than a 2-line one (running the `rm -rf` unconditionally, and getting rid of the `if`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes you are right. i didn't think about the job OP actually wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

In you second case you want to use:

```
cp -av test/$foldername/* test/destination/$foldername
```

That will copy the **contents** of `test/$foldername` to `test/destination/$foldername` overwriting any files of the same name that exist in `test/destination/$foldername`. Additionally, to preserve any (heaven forbid) spaces in `$foldername` you can quote the path/filename, but NOT the `*`:

```
cp -av "test/$foldername/"* "test/destination/$foldername"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will also end up in the "old" files of the destination directory still being there after the copying of the folder.
I think I have to use rm -rf solution. I will check this out...
Thank you anyway!!

Comment: No -- you are incorrect - or I don't understand. If you want to replace files of the **same** name with the new versions **my answer does that** -- any older files with the same name are **overwritten**. If you want to totally wipe out what is in `test/destination/$foldername` before copy, the use `rm -f`. There are no old files of the same name as those in `test/$foldername` that remain...

Comment: Yes, maybe it was not totally clear what I wanted. I want to "replace" the whole folder (not only single files) and therefore some files (which where present in the previous folder but are not in the newer one) shall be deleted. The rm -rf option worked for me.
Thanks for your help!!